# Java Websocket not connecting to server IP but connected to localhost

Tags: java, websocket

I am try to run a web socket on tomcat server but somehow its connected to localhost/127.0.0.1 host but not with server IP. Whenver i use my server ip the request seems to be lost and not reaching to my server while other service are working with same IP. How can i bind this web socket with specific IP. I have turn my windows firewall for this but still its not working

below is my code which i have written:

```
 @ServerEndpoint("/websocket")

    public class WebSocketTest {

           public  static Map<Session,Integer> sessionUserIdMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();


        @OnMessage
        public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws IOException,
                InterruptedException {
            System.out.println("User input: " + message);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello world Mr. " + message);
            // Sending message to client each 1 second
            for (int i = 0; i <= 25; i++) {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText(i + " Message from server");
                Thread.sleep(1000);

            }
        }

        @OnOpen
        public void onOpen(Session session) {
            System.out.println(session.getUserProperties().get("javax.websocket.endpoint.remoteAddress"));

            System.out.println("Client connected");
            int user_id = 0;
            try{
                String url = session.getRequestURI().toString().replaceAll("&encoding=text","");
                System.out.println(" url --> "+url);
                int index = url.lastIndexOf("abc=");
                user_id= Integer.parseInt(url.substring(index+4,url.length()));
                System.out.println("user_id connected"+user_id);

                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();

            }

            if(user_id !=0)
            sessionUserIdMap.put(session,user_id);
            //clients.add(session);

            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello world Mr. " + "Ram");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        @OnClose
        public void onClose(Session session) {
            System.out.println("Connection closed");
            try {
                session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello world Mr. " + "Ram closed");
                sessionUserIdMap.remove(session);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

       public static void sendMessage(int user_id) throws IOException{
           System.out.println("sendMessage cxallla");

           for(Session session:sessionUserIdMap.keySet()){
               System.out.println("sessionUserIdMap.get(session) "+sessionUserIdMap.get(session));
               if(sessionUserIdMap.get(session) == user_id){
                   System.out.println("Match Found");
                    session.getBasicRemote().sendText("this message is specific to "+user_id);

               }else{
                   System.out.println("Match not found");
               }
           }
       }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Can you ping the server, or Telnet to it on the same port?

Comment: yeah i can ping and see the response on the server for other services

Comment: i m using tomcat juli jar for this is that a problem ?

Comment: Can you telnet the server with 127.0.0.1 on port?

Comment: yes the telnet is working but issue here is its not connecting to Ip. I have to connect websocket from another server so in this case localhost/127.0.0.1 wont work/help